# How to implement blocking retry in spring kafka?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

**Using spring boot starter parent: 3.1.3.**

I am trying to implement blocking retry. Here is the simple reference implementation. But still it is not working. Any suggestion please.

```
@Component
public class KafkaConsumer {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConsumer.class);

    @KafkaListener(
            id = "${messages.id}",
            groupId = "${messages.group.id}",
            topics = "${messages.topic}"
    )
    public void consumeEvent(String event) {
        processEvent(event);
    }

    private void processEvent(String event) {
        try {
            Long number = Long.parseLong(event);
            log.info("The number is {}", number);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            throw new BlockingRetryException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaRetryConfiguration extends RetryTopicConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public void configureBlockingRetries(BlockingRetriesConfigurer blockingRetries) {
        blockingRetries
                .retryOn(BlockingRetryException.class)
                .backOff(new FixedBackOff(10000, 3));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureCustomizers(CustomizersConfigurer customizersConfigurer) {
        customizersConfigurer.customizeErrorHandler(eh -> eh.setSeekAfterError(false));
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    }
}
```

```
public class BlockingRetryException extends RuntimeException{
    public BlockingRetryException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

Still the blocking retry is not working.

Answer (score 0):

`RetryTopicConfigurationSupport` is only used when using [Non blocking retries](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#retry-topic) (`@RetryableTopic`) where you can specify which exceptions should be blocking Vs. non-blocking.

By default, when not using `@RetryableTopic`, all retries are blocking (when using the `DefaultErrorHandler`).

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-error-handling